# Есть код, выдает ошибку - IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

Есть код, выдает ошибку

> elif "#" == string[0] and "#" == string[1] and "#" == string[2] and "#" == string[3]: IndexError: string index out of range

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    string = input()
    if "%" == string[0] and "%" == string[1]:
        print(string[2:len(string) + 1])

    elif "#" == string[0] and "#" == string[1] and "#" == string[2] and "#" == string[3]:
        continue

    else:
        print(string)
```

Ввод:

```
12
ibiuH&tg7t628h####oij
nnkU%%jghlkhl
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuyyyyyy
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
###################
###444444444444444
#
%
yigigh
%%liuhli
####l;m;ol
oiho;i
```

Comment: ВВОД: 12
ibiuH&tg7t628h####oij
nnkU%%jghlkhl
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuyyyyyy
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
###################
###444444444444444
#
%
yigigh
%%liuhli
####l;m;ol
oiho;i

Comment: попробовал щас ваш код и этот ввод. нет ошибки. там только принт подвинуть правее пришлось, чтобы в элс попадал.

Comment: 12
ibiuH&tg7t628h####oij
nnkU%%jghlkhl
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuyyyyyy
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
###################
###444444444444444
#
%
yigigh
%%liuhli
####l;m;ol
oiho;i

Comment: Там не в строчку идет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на входе есть короткие строки (например, строка длиной 1), а вы безо всяких проверок берёте от неё символы с позиций 1, 2 и 3. Естественно, в этом месте возникнет ошибка "выход за границы".
Не проще ли брать срез (на нём таких ошибок не возникнет) и сразу проверять на совпадение подстрок, чем делать это посимвольно?

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    string = input()
    if "%%" == string[:2]:
        print(string[2:])

    elif "####" == string[:4]:
        continue

    else:
        print(string)
```